# Location of installed screensavers on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I just downloaded a screensaver that uses OpenGL and therefore runs really slowly without hardware acceleration. Unfortunately, my laptop has Intel integrated graphics. Luckily, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/750172/horrible-opengl-performance-on-intel-hd-graphics-laptop) had a solution, to rename the screensaver from `.scr` to `.sCr`

I renamed the copy of the screensaver in my downloads to `.sCr`, and when I ran it, it worked perfectly. Of course, the actual installed screensaver was still laggy, presumably because Windows copied it somewhere and kept `.scr` once I right clicked the downloaded copy and hit `Install`.

However, I am unable to find this place. I looked in `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, it wasn't in either. I don't want to have to resort to searching my entire drive (or even the whole windows folder).

I have Windows 7 SP1.

Where did Windows put my screensaver when I installed it?

Comment: You'd be surprised at how fast an "entire drive" search can run. Try this from a command prompt: `DIR %SYSTEMDRIVE%\*.scr /s` It might take a minute or two, but in general should still be relatively painless. Would probably be faster than waiting for an answer here. (To write mine, I'm actually doing the same right now.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem. The folder I downloaded it to was already on my system path, so installing it did nothing.

I'm still not sure why it doesn't lag when I hit "Test" in its context menu, but it lags when I actually wait for it to show up.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? Side note: I finally solved the problem of lag by making my own screensaver that launched the other one.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you're not seeing the files in `%WINDIR%\System32` or `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64`. Those are the primary storage locations for the default screensaver files.

To be sure of where the files on your system are, run the following command from an elevated CMD prompt:

```
DIR %SYSTEMDRIVE%\*.scr /s
```

That will search every folder, and subfolder, of your system drive (the drive Windows is installed to) for any file ending in .scr (case-insensitive). It may take a couple minutes to run, but is still the quickest and easiest way to find a file anywhere on the drive when you know its extension (or a significant part of its name).

If you want to narrow it down further, which can considerably speed up the process on a larger and/or fuller drive, use the following:

```
DIR %WINDIR%\*.scr /s
```

That will limit the search to only the Windows installation folder and its subdirectories. This took just a few seconds to complete on my system, whereas the previous command probably took a good minute or more.

Comment: Strange, I ran a search for all screensavers in the Windows folder and I only found the default ones. Mine is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: @ZoveGames Then it's probably not being copied there like you thought. Try running a tool like Process Monitor to see which file is being accessed when your screensaver runs.